# h3 dentro de table email marketing

Tags: html, css, email

Fala galera, Preciso aplicar um h3 dentro de uma tabela, em um td mas na posição bottom dele. Pois tenho uma imagem e preciso jogar um titulo para a imagem. Tentei com a aplicação de position mas não funciona nos clientes de email, podem me ajudar com uma solução para isso?

```
<td> 
     <img src='img/topo-oferta-aprovada-2.jpg' width='600' height='' alt='alt_text' border='0' align='center' style='width: 100%; max-width: 600px; height: auto; background: #dddddd; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 140%; color: #555555; margin: auto;'>
     <h3 valign='bottom' style='vertical-align: bottom; margin-left: 20px;color: #FFF;font-family: sans-serif;font-weight: bold;font-size: 20px; margin-top: -50px;'>Sua oferta foi aprovada</h3>
</td>
```

Obrigado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cristiando o pessoal está te negativando pq vc só colocou a imagem e não colocou o Código html/css. Por favor edite a sua pergunta com os código que só pela imagem não da para te ajudar muito.

Comment: Obrigado! Hugocsl

Comment: Experimentou por o align no TD em vez do H3?

Comment: Já e não funciona

Comment: Cara eu não tenho como fazer testes de envio de email aqui, mas tenta inspecionar o email e olha quais CSS o sistema de email não reconheceu. Olhando como o CSS chegou as vez vc pode ver o que o cliente de email desconsiderou do CSS que foi enviado...

Comment: @hugocsl o que ele esta desconsiderando position: relative

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cristiano fiz umas correções no seu CSS para ficar alinhado etc. *Se não funcionar no seu projeto é porque tem algum outro CSS interferindo no seu elemento, nesse caso vc teria que colocar `!importante` em alguns estilos*

**EDIT:** Repare que foi preciso colocar `display:flex` na `<dt>` agora pode ser que funciona já que com o `position` não deu certo...

Veja o exemplo abaixo.

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
                <img src="http://placecage.com/600/200" width="600" height="" alt="alt_text" border="0" align="center" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px; height: auto; background: #dddddd; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 140%; color: #555555; margin: auto;">
                <h3 valign="bottom" style="vertical-align: bottom; text-align: center; padding: 10px 0; color: #FFF; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; margin-top: -50px; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);">Sua oferta foi aprovada</h3>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: recebo desta maneira @hugocsl https://prnt.sc/javynj

Comment: o que ele esta desconsiderando position: relative

Comment: @CristianoFacirolli cara eu editei a minha resposta, testa com esse código agora. Eu tive que usar display flex na TD para não precisar usar position. Testa se deu certo e me fala

Comment: Deu certo @hugocsl , desculpe pela demora em responder

Comment: @CristianoFacirolli que bom que deu certo! Se a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marca-la como Aceita, nesse ícone ✔ abaixo das setinhas no lado esquerdo da minha resposta :) assim o site não fica com perguntas abertas pendentes sem resposta aceita.

Comment: Show, aceita! =)